# one to one mapping on different column names

Tags: xml, hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

I have two different tables, `Person` table and `Employee` table. I need a one-to-one mapping between these two. `Employee` table's `emp_id` references `Person` table's `id`. I need some help in writing the mapping xml.

**person.hbm.xml:**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Persons" table="Persons">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME" type="java.lang.String">
    </property>
    <one-to-many name="employee" column="per_id" unique="true" class="Persons"
      not-null="true"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**employee.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Employee" table="Employee">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name_id" column="NAME_ID" type="java.lang.String">
    </property>
    <property name="emp_id" column="emp_ID" type="java.lang.String">
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How do I write the mapping taking `emp_id` of `Employee` table and `id` from `Persons` table?

*Note:* `id` of `Persons` table is the primary key

Answer (score 0):

In **employee.hbm.xml** :

```
<many-to-one name="person" class="Persons" column="emp_ID" />
```

**To make the relationship bidirectional you can add the following in person.hbm.xml:**

```
<one-to-one name="employee" class="Employee" property-ref="person"/>
```

It will be more understandable and not confusing to others, if you could modify the emp_ID column(foriegn key column) in employee table that refers persons table "id" column to person_id

Employee Table:

Rename emp_ID --> person_id